# Can we create an instance of a class by combining constructors in Java?

Tags: java

Please have a look at the snippet of the code below which I stumbled upon while reading this [java tutorial on creating objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html).

```
    // Declare and create a point object and two rectangle objects.
    Point originOne = new Point(23, 94);
    Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(originOne, 100, 200);
    Rectangle rectTwo = new Rectangle(50, 100);
```

The `rectOne` object is created by passing an object of `Point` class i.e. `originOne` and `width` and `height` of the rectangle. If you have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) of `Rectangle` class, you come to know that there is no such constructor in the documentations which is accepting three parameters (i.e. A point, width and height). However there are seperate constructors, one of them taking a point of class `Point` as parameter

```
Rectangle(Point p)
```

and the other one taking width and height of the rectangle as parameter

```
Rectangle(int width, int height)
```

I was wondering can you combine constructors, as done by the snippet of the code I shared above from the tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you do not use the `java.awt.Rectangle`. In this tutorial they use an own implementation of the Rectangle class which have such a constructor.

Comment: I did not notice it, on the tutoria page, they are linking to their own `Rectangle` class [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/examples/Rectangle.java)

Answer (score 1):

Combining constructors? No such thing in `Java`.You can convert

```
Point originOne = new Point(23, 94);
Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(originOne, 100, 200);
```

To

```
Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(new Point(23, 94), 100, 200);//not a Combining.
```

Rectangle already has a constructor that accepts Point.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't combine two constructors the way you suggest. [Rectangle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/examples/Rectangle.java) does have a 3 parameters constructor :

```
public Rectangle(Point p, int w, int h) {
    origin = p;
    width = w;
    height = h;
}
```

The Rectangle class you referred to in your documentation link in not related to the one used in the tutorial.

What you could do is call one constructor from another constructor. For example, a constructor with 3 parameters can first call a constructor that only has the first two parameters, and then initialize the 3rd parameter.

For example, the Rectangle constructor can be re-written as :

```
public Rectangle(Point p, int w, int h) {
    this (p);
    width = w;
    height = h;
}
```

or

```
public Rectangle(Point p, int w, int h) {
    this (w,h);
    origin = p;
}
```

Comment: This is just an example class and not the class from the java awt library he is using

Comment: can you link to the documentations page please? where there it documents a three parameters constructor?

Comment: @ultimate What you said seems closer to be correct.

Comment: @ultimate He started by referring to a Java tutorial. That tutorial has a link to the Rectangle class it uses (which is not the awt Rectangle).

Comment: @segmentationfaulter The Rectangle class used in the " java tutorial on creating objects." is just an example. It's not part of any official Java library, and has no Javadoc.

Comment: @Eran I'm sorry - I missed that. I was assuming he is using the class he has linked the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) for.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. You can only use the constructors that have already been defined as they are. The best approach is to use the constructor that is most suitable for your use case and use setter methods to assign your additional properties.

```
Point originOne = new Point(23, 94);
Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(originOne);
rectOne.setSize(100, 200);
```

or

```
Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(originOne.getX(), originOne.getY(), 100, 200);
```

or

```
Dimension dimension = new Dimension(100, 200);
Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(originOne, dimension);
```

It depends on you :)

Answer (score 0):

[Rectangle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) offers 7 constructors with different arguments of types `int`, `Point` and `Dimension`.
Unfortunalely there is no constructor mixing `int` with `Point` or `Dimension` as you asked for.

Instead you have the following options:

1. pass only ints (by getting them from the point)

   ```
   Point originOne = new Point(23, 94);
   Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(originOne.x, originOne.y, 100, 200);
   ```
2. pass a dimension as the second argument

   ```
   Point originOne = new Point(23, 94);
   Dimension sizeOne = new Dimension(100, 200);
   Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(originOne, sizeOne);
   ```

For the rectangle without origin you can use

```
    Dimension sizeTwo = new Dimension(50, 100);
    Rectangle rectTwo = new Rectangle(sizeTwo);
```

This way you can even easily reuse the origin or the size for different rectangles.